Error: Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins
Describe the bug
Nativewind/babel
Exact error:
Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins
To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:
Setup a new react-native project using expo/nativewind
Set up nativewind according to the docs
See error
Expected behavior
Expected the app to load with styling
Can everyone help me with this issue, please?
issue

You need to set up a new React Native using Expo or Nativewind as this error happens when sth in CSS expects async behavior. However, it is not handled properly. You can share the Package.json or babel.config.js to figure it out together much quicker.
